# How to do a mass update in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I am wondering how do a mass update? I want to do a where clause and grab all items that meet that where clause `Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToList()` then do an update on all of them.

```
// change every name to bob
A.Name = "bob"
// then do a mass update
```

Do I have to do a foreach loop? And go through each one and then send it to be updated or is there another way to do this?

Thanks

**Edit**

I have this

```
// in my repo;
  private readonly ISession session;

 // session done with ninject IOC
public MyRepo(ISession session)
{
   this.session = session;
}

public void MassUpdate(int id, string prefix)
{
         var query = "UPDATE TableA SET Name= (:prefix) WHERE Id IN (:Id)";
          session.CreateQuery(query).SetParameter("prefix", prefix).SetParameter("Id",Id);
}

 public void Insert(MyClass myClass)
 {
    sesson.save(myClass);
 }

public void Commit()
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
     {
                    transaction.Commit();
     }
}

 // service layer method

 public void myMethod()
 {
     MyClass myClass = nw MyClass() { Name = "test"};
     MyRepo r = new Repo();
     r.MassUpdate(1,"bob");
     r.Insert(myClass);
     r.Commit();
 }
```

So how can I setup my MassUpdate to execute on Commit(). Note that this commit is used for all methods in MyRepo so I can't stick the execute in the commit method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding Diego's answer's, you can use HQL to send a list of arguments:

```
var person = 25;
var query = "update Foo set Name = 'bob' where id = :person";
var update = session.CreateQuery(query)
                    .SetParameter("person", person);


/***
 *
 * Do Stuff
 *
 ***/

 update.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: @binaryhowl - Can you do this with the linq method?

Comment: @chobo2 - Not without loading all the entities to memory first.

Comment: @binaryhowl - I guess this way is less memory intensive then?

Comment: @chobo2 - Yes. Doing this with linq and foreach forces each object to be modified to *gasp* load from the database and then update, whereas this won't load nor require anything from the database.

Comment: @ binaryhowl - Can I delay the it to do the save at a later time? I not sure if I am to crazy of it doing the update right away. Could I do other things then use commit?

Comment: @chobo2 - From my experience, I have noticed using the NHibernate Profiler that _at least_ on an Oracle database, the update will fire as soon as I perform the ExecuteUpdate(), so in that case, you would want to save the query and then ExecuteUpdate() when you desire.

Comment: @ binaryhowl - How would I save it for later?

Comment: @binaryhowl - doing it this way is not open to sql inject attacks right?

Comment: @binaryhowl - is this how you do place holders in nhibernate? (:people)

Comment: @binaryHowl - also my where clause is only one "id" so how do I make that. Your using a collection where I just need a single int.

Comment: @chobo2 - HQL is not open to SQL Injection... at all.

Comment: @chobo2 - Not necessarily. Parenthesis are the SQL syntax for a filter by a collection. More on http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 4):

```
session.CreateQuery("update Foo set Name = 'bob' where id = 1")
       .ExecuteUpdate()
```

Comment: @ Diego Mijelshon - Do you have to do a ExecuteUpdate right away or can you do a commit at a later point?

Comment: @chobo2: ExecuteUpdate executes immediately (internally, it maps the query to SQL and uses IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()). You can still wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon - How would I wrap it around?

Comment: @chobo2: `using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction) {...}`

Comment: @chobo2: You are not calling ExecuteUpdate anywhere.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon - Well I was tryingto not use ExecuteUpdate Period. I have this. A method that would setup the query, a service layer that would call this method and after that might call many other methods. Then when I done all the queries I need to do I want to do one commit. So then I would call my Commit method. I will update what I have to show what I doing. So where does execute query fit in?

Comment: @chobo2: you can't do that. ExecuteUpdate is manual. If you are looking for automatic mass-updates, configure `adonet.batch_size` instead.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon - So there is no way I can make it wait to be executed with all other queries?

Comment: @chobo2 There always is. Keep an ICollection<IQuery> with all your "deferred queries" and execute them all together when committing.

Comment: @diego-mijelshon - can u give an example?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon  - So your saying I keep the query result then? do .ExecutueUpdate?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is a late answer but just so you know a better solution (without query in plain text) exists here : [Linq to Nhibernate Bulk Update Query Equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114191/linq-to-nhibernate-bulk-update-query-equivalent/47053935#47053935)

In your case it would be applied like this:

```
session.Query<TableA>().Where(f => f.Id == id)
            .Update(i => new Foo { prefix = myPrefix });
```